# VB.NET in Visual Studio 2008 on Vista 32bit building a WSP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, web-parts, wsp

I am trying to build a WSP file in VS2008 on my VB.NET project. How would I go about doing this? I can find a lot of plugins for C# but not VB.NET.

Comment: What's an ESP file, and is it like a WSP file? BTW, what's a WSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your file is a sharepoint web part, but if it is, you can use sharepoint tools for visual studio. Then you can simply create a new project -> Sharepoint -> WebPart

Answer (score 0):

WSPBuilder is the quickest and easiest way I have yet found to both build and deploy WSPs.

There is a good integration with VS2008.

It can be downloaded from here;

http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

Trust me, if you are doing this manually then this tool is going to be the greatest thing you ever used...

I would not use the MS Visual Studio Extensions as they are not flexible enough for most developments.